# IUrlHelper.Action method returns null value when passing RouteValueDictionary in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have migrated an application from ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC to ASP.NET 6 Core MVC. I am facing an issue with urlhelper.action method.

IurlHelper.Action method is returning null value when passing `RouteValueDictionary` in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

```
IUrlHelper urlHelper;

var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(RouteValue);

var values = urlHelper.Action(AspAction, AspController, routeValues);
```

Value is null when passing `routeValues` but on removing this route values give some result at least.

Please help.

I tried removing the routevalue variable and check if it gives some result at least which it gives but that is not my solution. I need to create a URL like `/test/12345/main?page=1&count=1`.

But I am getting null. On removing the `routevalue` variable I am getting `/test/12345/main`

```
   //small code snippet

   public string CreateUrl(int pageNo, IUrlHelper urlHelper, int pageCount)
    {        
        var routeValue = new RouteValueDictionary(this.RouteValue); // RouteValue is Dictionary object

        if (this.PageNumber != null) //string property
        {
            routeValue[this.PageNumber] = pageNo;
           
            if (pageCount != 0)
            {
                routeValue[this.PageCount] = pageCount; //this.pageCount is string property                  
            }
        }

        if (this.AspArea != null) //string property
        {
            routeValue["area"] = this.AspArea;
        }          
        return urlHelper.Action(this.AspAction, this.AspController,routeValues); // this is returning null in mvc .net core 6.0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a URL like /test/12345/main?page=1&count=1.

It’s available as a property of the controller. ControllerBase.Url is an IUrlHelper instance. Read [Action(IUrlHelper, String, String, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-action(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object)) to know more.

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

In Program.cs, add`test`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "test/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

HomeCntroller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("test")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var url2 = Url.Action("main", "12345", new { page =1, count = 1 });
            return View();
        }
   }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Qing , This answer is Ok but doesn't works for me because I need to read the values from routeValues Disctionary . Because when I pass this routeValue  dictionary it returns me null.

Comment: @raj_Udai20072020 ok, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Added snippet in comment.

Comment: @raj_Udai20072020 I set the breakpoint at `var routeValue = new RouteValueDictionary(this.RouteValue);` I see the routeValue is null here.

Comment: this.RouteValue is Dictionary of string. Please let me know if url.Action method is even supported in .Net 6 Core because it worked in .net Core 3.1

Comment: @raj_Udai20072020  Could you share minimal reproducible example like github ? Because your  url.Action method is IUrlHelper, my is ControllerBase.Url is an IUrlHelper instance.